# Running Pester Tests inside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, powershell-tools

After installing `PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2015` I created a new `Powershell Module Project` which creates a `MyProject.psd1` a `MyProject.psm1` and a `MyProject.tests.ps1` file.

MyProject.tests.ps1 file looks like this

```
Describe "Connect-Database" {
    Context "When Connection To Database" {
        $result = Connect-Database -host localhost -user admin -pass pass
        It "Should Return True" {
            $result | Should Be $True
        }
    }
}
```

Connect-Database is a function from `MyProject.psm1` and is exported via `MyProject.psd1`

```
# Functions to export from this module
FunctionsToExport = 'Connect-Database'
```

Running a powershell console and executing

```
Import-Module .\MyProject.psd1
Invoke-Pester
```

works great and returns

```
Describing Connect-Database
   Context When Connection To Database
    [+] Should Return True 627ms
Tests completed in 627ms
Passed: 1 Failed: 0 Skipped: 0 Pending: 0
```

Here comes my problem: PowerShell Tools come with a test adapter and my test shows in Test Explorer.

But If I execute it, it always fails with `The term Connect-Database is not recognized as cmdlet function script file or operable program`

Even adding `Import-Module .\MyProject.psd1` to the `MyProject.tests.ps1` file does not help. Any ideas how to load my module prior to running the tests?

Answer (score 4):

I added `Get-Location | Write-Host` to MyProject.tests.ps1 file and figured out that the working directory was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`

I didn't check that in the first place because I believed the test adapter would just execute `Invoke-Pester` in the working directory

Eventually I solved this with

```
Split-Path $PSCommandPath | Set-Location
Import-Module (".\" + (Split-Path -Leaf $PSCommandPath).Replace(".tests.ps1", ".psd1"))
```